# antd Table warning Warning: Tree missing follow keys

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6DEL.png) I have multiple tables that can be checked out of the loop. If I cycle multiple tables, this warning will be reported as long as one item is checked, and no warning will be reported if it is not checked or unchecked Solve it Thank you

I tried to give the Table a unique key root with a unique rowKey="id", because I loop each item of data has a unique id can or will have this warning, the way I am currently using is that all tables have a state in the checked state I don't expect that warning
My code is as follows：

```
const rowSelection: TableRowSelection<any> = {
    selectedRowKeys: check,
    onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows, _) => {
        const selectedRowKeys = dataSoucre(selectedRows)
        const flag = false
        // 不支持分票情况，子集勾选兄弟根父级都勾选
        if (flag) {
            if (selected) {
                const resultIds = selectedRowKeys.map((id: any) => findIds(waybillData, id));
                const newCheck = Array.from(new Set(resultIds.flat()));
                setCheck(Array.from(new Set([...check, newCheck].flat())))
            } else {
                // 取消勾选
                if (record?.id.startsWith('parent')) {
                    cancelParent(record)
                } else {
                    const newCheck = check.filter((ele: any) => !findIds(waybillData, record?.id).includes(ele))
                    setCheck([...newCheck])
                }
            }
        } else {
            // 支持分票正常勾选
            if (selected) {
                addCheck(selectedRowKeys)
            } else {
                // 取消勾选
                if (record?.id.startsWith('parent')) {
                    cancelParent(record)
                } else {
                    const newCheck = check?.filter((item: any) => item !== record?.id)
                    setCheck([...newCheck])
                }
            }
        }

    },
    onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => {
        const selectedRowKeys = dataSoucre(selectedRows)
        if (selected) {
            addCheck(selectedRowKeys)
        } else {
            const cancel = changeRows?.map((item: any) => item.id)?.filter((ele: any) => !ele.startsWith('parent'))
            const newCheck = check?.filter((fid: any) => !cancel.includes(fid))
            setCheck([...newCheck])
        }
    }
};
// 勾选的情况
const addCheck = (selectedRowKeys: any) => {
    selectedRowKeys?.forEach((ele: any) => {
        const isCon = check.some((resultItem: any) => resultItem === ele);
        if (!isCon) {
            check.push(ele)
        }
    })
    setCheck([...check])
}
// 取消勾选，选中父级的情况
const cancelParent = (record:any) => {
      // 用于存储符合条件的 children 的 id
      const childrenIds: any = [];
      // 找到外层 id 相等的对象
      const targetObjects = waybillData.filter((obj: any) => obj.waybillList.some((waybill: any) => waybill.id === record.id));
      // 提取符合条件的对象的 children 的 id
      targetObjects.forEach((obj: any) => {
          obj.waybillList.forEach((waybill: any) => {
              if (waybill.id === record.id) {
                  waybill.children.forEach((child: any) => {
                      childrenIds.push(child.id);
                  });
              }
          });
      });
      const newCheck = check?.filter((item: any) => !childrenIds.includes(item))
      setCheck([...newCheck])

}
const dataSoucre = (selectedRows:any) => {
   return selectedRows?.map((item: any) => item?.id)?.filter((item: any) => item !== '' && !item.startsWith('parent'))
}
// 拿到任意一个子级的 id 去找所有兄弟 id 如果是父级，返回即可
function findIds(data: any, idToFind: any) {
    const result = [];
    for (const item of data) {
        const waybillList = item.waybillList;
        for (const waybill of waybillList) {
            if (waybill.id === idToFind) {
                result.push(waybill.id);
            } else {
                const children = waybill.children;
                for (const child of children) {
                    if (child.id === idToFind) {
                        const childIds = children.map((childItem: any) => childItem.id);
                        result.push(...childIds);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
waybillData?.map((item: any, index: number) =>
            <ProTable<any>
                scroll={{ x: 1600 }}
                columns={columns}
                className={styles.tables}
                dataSource={item?.waybillList || []}
                rowKey='id'
                key={index}
                editable={{
                    type: 'multiple',
                }}
                pagination={false}
                search={false}
                options={false}
                dateFormatter="string"
                toolbar={{
                    subTitle: <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                        <HomeOutlined style={{ marginTop: '-6px', color: '#FF8450', marginRight: '15px' }} />
                        <h4 style={{ marginRight: '15px' }}>{item?.warehouse?.name}</h4>
                        <span style={{ marginRight: '15px', color: '#4071FF' }}>{item?.waybillList?.length}<span style={{ color: '#333' }}>&nbsp;票</span></span>
                        <span style={{ marginRight: '15px', color: '#4071FF' }}>{item?.waybillList?.reduce((prev: any, cur: any) => prev + cur?.pieceNum, 0) || 0}<span style={{ color: '#333' }}>&nbsp;件</span></span>
                    </div>
                }}
                rowSelection={{ ...rowSelection, checkStrictly: false }} />)
```

Comment: please add a snippet of your code